# Finding files by their owner and file permissions

Tags: find

I'm trying to `find` files which are owned and have the primary group of `root`. Is there a parameter available to search for files like this? It's critical that all files in a certain directory *not* be owned by `root`, so I'd like to check periodically to make sure that someone on the server isn't accidentally creating files owned by `root` (namely me). Sure, `chown -R user:user /path` works, but I'd like to be able to check.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

man find:

> ```
>   -group gname
>          File belongs to group gname (numeric group ID allowed).
>   -user uname
>          File is owned by user uname (numeric user ID allowed).
> ```

Comment: So obvious... Anyone else looked into the man page and searched for '-owner' instead of '-user'?

Comment: It's not obvious that the word is `user` for sure. Somehow I was imagining an option like find -chmod